# isn't the db4o .OpenFile method supposed to create the filestructure if it doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, db4o

When using Db4oFactiory.OpenFile("somename"); it was trying to drop the folder "somename" into the visual studio directory and getting denied permission. I solved this by giving it an absolute path:

```
        db = Db4oFactory.OpenFile("E:/test-projects/db4o/db");
```

and now I'm catching a FileNotFoundException but the db4o docs explicitly say that if there isnt a db already in play, that OpenFile will generate them. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you have to suffix a file extension. I was thinking that it would need more than one file and thus need a directory.